# How to extract a single value from JSON response (with Python)?

Tags: python

Hi I'm working on a project with a colleague of mine but we stopped.
We can't extract a single element of a JSON response.
We have to extrapolate the `"mood"` attribute from the code that I am attaching, thanks to all in advance:

```
{
    u'operation_id': u'5526bd03b2e448ea8d2f3e96ae5ba88c', 
    u'photos': [
    {
        u'height': 280,
        u'pid': u'F@01aa37a755638d436b6d527a18da96bc_ffc4e38fc72b2',
        u'tags': [
        {
            u'attributes':
            {
                u'age_est':
                {
                    u'confidence': 50,
                    u'value': u'27'
                },
                u'anger':
                {
                    u'confidence': 0,
                    u'value': u'false'
                },
                u'beard':
                {
                    u'confidence': 91,
                    u'value': u'true'
                },
                u'dark_glasses':
                {
                    u'confidence': 48,
                    u'value': u'false'
                },
                u'disgust':
                {
                    u'confidence': 0,
                    u'value': u'false'
                },
                u'ethnicity':
                {
                    u'asian':
                    {
                        u'confidence': 7,
                        u'value': u'false'
                    },
                    u'black':
                    {
                        u'confidence': 2,
                        u'value': u'false'
                    },
                    u'hispanic':
                    {
                        u'confidence': 3,
                        u'value': u'false'
                    },
                    u'indian':
                    {
                        u'confidence': 3,
                        u'value': u'false'
                    },
                    u'white':
                    {
                        u'confidence': 85,
                        u'value': u'true'
                    }
                },
                u'eyes':
                {
                    u'confidence': 30,
                    u'value': u'open'
                },
                u'face':
                {
                    u'confidence': 95,
                    u'value': u'true'
                },
                u'fear':
                {
                    u'confidence': 0,
                    u'value': u'false'
                },
                u'gender':
                {
                    u'confidence': 83,
                    u'value': u'male'
                },
                u'glasses':
                {
                    u'confidence': 26,
                    u'value': u'false'
                },
                u'happiness':
                {
                    u'confidence': 100,
                    u'value': u'true'
                },
                u'hat':
                {
                    u'confidence': 29,
                    u'value': u'false'
                },
                u'lips':
                {
                    u'confidence': 53,
                    u'value': u'parted'
                },
                u'liveness':
                {
                    u'confidence': 66,
                    u'value': u'true'
                },
                u'mood':
                {
                    u'confidence': 100,
                    u'value': u'happy'
                },
                u'neutral_mood':
                {
                    u'confidence': 0,
                    u'value': u'false'
                },
                u'sadness':
                {
                    u'confidence': 0,
                    u'value': u'false'
                },
                u'smiling':
                {
                    u'confidence': 84,
                    u'value': u'true'
                },
                u'surprise':
                {
                    u'confidence': 0,
                    u'value': u'false'
                }
            },
            u'center':
            {
                u'x': 40.15,
                u'y': 38.93
            },
            u'confirmed': False,
            u'eye_left':
            {
                u'confidence': 98,
                u'id': 449,
                u'x': 44.89,
                u'y': 34.29
            },
            u'eye_right':
            {
                u'confidence': 98,
                u'id': 450,
                u'x': 36.16,
                u'y': 33.93
            },
            u'height': 39.64,
            u'label': None,
            u'manual': False,
            u'mouth_center':
            {
                u'confidence': 91,
                u'id': 615,
                u'x': 41.15,
                u'y': 47.14
            },
            u'nose':
            {
                u'confidence': 99,
                u'id': 403,
                u'x': 41.4,
                u'y': 40.71
            },
            u'pitch': -3,
            u'points': None,
            u'recognizable': True,
            u'similarities': None,
            u'tid': u'TEMP_F@01aa37a755638d436b6d527a00a1006d_ffc4e38fc72b2_40.15_38.93_0_1',
            u'uids': [],
            u'width': 19.7,
            u'yaw': -4
        }],
        u'url': u'http://api.skybiometry.com/fc/images/get?id=bmN2X3hybD1xd3RhY2FvcXJnYzFpMXdkMjIwNGZ4YXB6dCZuY3ZfZnJwZXJnPXZiM3liOXIyOXlmZ25lNjB0bjdvdzlycHRvJmVxPTI3NTMmY3ZxPXNzcDRyMzhzcDcybzImZ3Z6cmZnbnpjPTIwMjExMjE1MTUxNjMz',
        u'width': 401
    }], u'status': u'success', u'usage':
    {
        u'limit': 100,
        u'remaining': 80,
        u'reset_time': 1639553771,
        u'reset_time_text': u'Wed, 15 December 2021 07:36:11 +0000',
        u'used': 20
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not JSON, that's a Python 2 dict.

Comment: `data["photos"][0]["tags"][0]["attributes"]["mood"]`

Comment: @JohnGordon wow, great minds think alike :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty-printing your data makes it a lot easier to analyze. Once you do that, as in my edit above, you'll see that you can access `"mood"` via `data["photos"][0]["tags"][0]["attributes"]["mood"]`, assuming your dict is named `data`.

You need the numeric list indices because both `"photos"` and `"tags"` are lists containing a single element - a dict.

Comment: perfect thanks, now it works